# How can I convert columns of string in dataset to int?

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn

Some of the data in the dataset are in string format and I should map all of them to the numeric form. I want to convert string data in some columns in the dataset to int int to become usable in the knn method. I wrote this code but It has this error. How can I fix it?
thank you for your consideration.

here is the dataset:
http://gitlab.rahnemacollege.com/rahnemacollege/tuning-registration-JusticeInWork/raw/master/dataset.csv

this error is in this part of code:

```
     def string_to_int(s):
       ord3 = lambda x : '%.3d' % ord(x)
       return int(''.join(map(ord3, s)))
     for i in range(1,24857):
       df.iloc[i,0]=string_to_int(df.iloc[i,0])
       df.iloc[i,1]=string_to_int(df.iloc[i,1])
       df.iloc[i,3]=string_to_int(df.iloc[i,3])
       df.iloc[i,8]=string_to_int(df.iloc[i,8]) 
       df.iloc[i,9]=string_to_int(df.iloc[i,9])
       df.iloc[i,10]=string_to_int(df.iloc[i,10]) 
       df.iloc[i,11]=string_to_int(df.iloc[i,11])
       df.iloc[i,12]=string_to_int(df.iloc[i,12])
```

the error is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-f5bce11c577a> in <module>()
     30    df.iloc[i,10]=string_to_int(df.iloc[i,10])
     31    df.iloc[i,11]=string_to_int(df.iloc[i,11])
---> 32    df.iloc[i,12]=string_to_int(df.iloc[i,12])
 33 
 34 

<ipython-input-7-f5bce11c577a> in string_to_int(s)
 20 def string_to_int(s):
 21    ord3 = lambda x : '%.3d' % ord(x)
 ---> 22    return int(''.join(map(ord3, s)))
    23 
    24 for i in range(1, 24857):

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

the total code is here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from google.colab import files
!pip install sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
#-----------------read file-------------------
uploaded = files.upload()
with open('dataset.csv', 'r') as data:
   df3 = pd.read_csv(data , encoding = ('ansi'))
   lst = ['id', 'Prold', 'ProCreationId', 'CustCreatonRate', 'TaskCreationTimestamp',     'Price', 'ServiceId', 'CategoryId', 'ZoneId', 'TaskState', 'TargetProId', 'isFraud']
   df = pd.DataFrame(df3)
   print (df)

#----------------------preprocessing----------------

def string_to_int(s):
   ord3 = lambda x : '%.3d' % ord(x)
   return int(''.join(map(ord3, s)))

for i in range(1,24857):
   df.iloc[i,0]=string_to_int(df.iloc[i,0])
   df.iloc[i,1]=string_to_int(df.iloc[i,1])
   df.iloc[i,3]=string_to_int(df.iloc[i,3])
   df.iloc[i,8]=string_to_int(df.iloc[i,8]) 
   df.iloc[i,9]=string_to_int(df.iloc[i,9])
   df.iloc[i,10]=string_to_int(df.iloc[i,10]) 
   df.iloc[i,11]=string_to_int(df.iloc[i,11])
   df.iloc[i,12]=string_to_int(df.iloc[i,12])
```

Comment: what exactly is that "string format", does it follow an existing standard? I am a bit skeptical about the scheme you present, that converts each char into the 3-digit ascii code of that char (e.g. `'bKv...'` into `98075118...`). How would `1000` be encoded?

Comment: besides the fact that there are `NaN` in the data, as @SeabNavin mentioned, I suspect your code could be greatly simplified and clarified. But first, we must understand the encoding standard.

Comment: here is the sample of its data: FDPHLhrcjx3Gww4syg43Po

Comment: I have also mentioned the link of dataset in question which is: http://gitlab.rahnemacollege.com/rahnemacollege/tuning-registration-JusticeInWork/raw/master/dataset.csv

Comment: Yes, I had already carefully looked at the data, and also looked in that repo to see if there was an explanation about the encoding, but there is nothing else beside the csv file. I remain skeptical about your interpretation of these Id values.

Comment: For example, a more plausible encoding scheme for "Id" quantities might be `base64` encoding, with trailing `'=='` dropped. Perhaps these `Id`s were even `UUID` originally. If so, the first `TargetProdId` would be `uuid.UUID(bytes=base64.decodebytes(b'vqUkxUDuEmB7gHWQvcYrBn=='))` which is, in `str` form: `'bea524c5-40ee-1260-7b80-7590bdc62b06'`.  These are all hypothetical, of course.

Comment: @Pierre D thank you. sorry, your comment which included import struct in the beginning of it, is no longer available here for me. can you comment this again please? thank you for your pleasure.

Comment: sure, I added it back, but as mentioned I doubt it makes much of a difference in this case.

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: I updated pandas but It cause this error yet: TypeError:   applymap() got an unexpected keyword argument 'na_action'

Comment: side note: the 4 comments above this one should really have been made on the answer instead, not on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NaN` values come from empty strings in the original csv file. To leave those as empty strings instead, you could read the csv with `df = pd.read_csv(url, keep_default_na=False)`, although having them as `NaN` can make it easier to deal with them.

As noted in the comments however, I am skeptical of the correct interpretation of the encoding standard (if any) used in that data.

But if that is as described in the question, then you can use your function `string_to_int` without change, apply it to all `'...Id'` columns and skip the `NaN` (and optionally convert those to another value):

```py
id_cols = [k for k in df.columns if k.lower().endswith('id')]

df2 = df.copy()
df2[id_cols] = df2[id_cols].applymap(string_to_int, na_action='ignore')

# optional: convert nan to some int value (here: 0)
df2[id_cols] = df2[id_cols].fillna(0)
```

#### Outcome

```py
>>> df2['TargetProId'].head()
0    1181130851071200850681170691090660551030720870...
1    8911811810612110611210908812010605205108207407...
2                                                    0
3                                                    0
4                                                    0
Name: TargetProId, dtype: object
```

(Note: the dtype is still `object` because the int values are overflowing `int64`, and are instead Python's arbitrary-precision int objects; `df2.applymap(type).value_counts()` shows that all `'id'` columns are `<class 'int'>`).

#### Original suggestion

Initially I had this other suggestion for `string_to_int()`. It handles non-str values explicitly with a default value. It also uses `struct.unpack()` as a basis for more performant decoding, although in this specific case, I doubt it makes much difference.

```py
import struct

def string_to_int2(s, default=0):
    if isinstance(s, str):
        n = len(s)
        b = s.encode('ascii')
        return int(''.join([f'{v:03d}' for v in struct.unpack(f'{n}B', b)]))
    return default

df2 = df.copy()
df2[id_cols] = df2[id_cols].applymap(string_to_int2)
```

Comment: @hsi: what version of Pandas did you upgrade to?  `na_action` was [introduced in 1.2](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html).

Comment: It works. Thank you for your response I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your 12th column (TargetProId) in the data set has NaN value(it is a null value in dataframe).
so you need to replace it with other string.
For example you can replace the na value with "Unknown".

```
df["TargetProId"]=df["TargetProId"].fillna("Unknown")
```